# How to run a function and get a value and add it in text in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have written the following code below in Flutter

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';


void main() => runApp(Myapp());



class Myapp extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  MaterialApp(

  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Hello World'),
    centerTitle: true,
    backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
  ),
 
  body: Center(child: MyStatefulWidget(),
),
)
    );
  }
}

class Weather extends StatefulWidget {
 UpdateTextState createState() => UpdateTextState();
}

class UpdateTextState extends State {
    // var textHolder = 'Getting';
    
    weath() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    print(position.latitude);
    print(position.longitude);
    var url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${position.latitude}&lon=${position.longitude}&appid=myapiid';
    print(url);
    var response = await http.get(url);
    var dart  = json.decode(response.body);
    var dartt = dart['main'];
    var climate = dartt['temp'];
    var weather = climate - 32 * 5/9;  
    // print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
    // print('Response body: ${json.decode(response.body)}');
    // print(dart['main']);
    // print(dartt['temp']);
    var textHolder = '${weather.toString()}C';
    return textHolder;
    }
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   var c  = weath();
   //print(textHolder);
    //changeText();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 20),
          child: Text(c),
          ),

        
      ]))
    );
  }
}
```

if I run this program this is the output I am getting [Please refer to This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibzZX.png) actually I want the weather that I get from the API which is text holder variable please Help me guys I have even tried without return statement too also I have tried adding the function directly which also didn't work out well basically is there any alternate way or did I make any mistake in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just use setState((){}). Don't use return weath(), because async is a background thread and textView need UI.**

```
 var c = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    
    super.initState();
    weath()
    
  }


  weath() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
     
    var url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${position.latitude}&lon=${position.longitude}&appid=myapiid';
    print(url);
    var response = await http.get(url);
    var dart  = json.decode(response.body);
    var dartt = dart['main'];
    var climate = dartt['temp'];
    var weather = climate - 32 * 5/9;  
    setState(() { 
       c = '${weather}C'; } ); 

    }
```

Comment: Hello man Thanks for your response I tried this piece of code vs code is telling me like this https://paste.pics/cd24e7ad8beb0c83a245a73e6bd100d3 and on my UI its blank

Comment: setState(() {
    c = '${weather}C';
    });    also see edited ans

Answer (score 1):

It's a Future so you can call it in your initState and use setState to update the `c` variable. or you can use FutureBuilder.

```dart
class Weather extends StatefulWidget {
  UpdateTextState createState() => UpdateTextState();
}

class UpdateTextState extends State {
   var c = 'Getting';

  weath() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    print(position.latitude);
    print(position.longitude);
    var url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${position.latitude}&lon=${position.longitude}&appid=myapiid';
    print(url);
    var response = await http.get(url);
    var dart  = json.decode(response.body);
    var dartt = dart['main'];
    var climate = dartt['temp'];
    var weather = climate - 32 * 5/9;
    // print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
    // print('Response body: ${json.decode(response.body)}');
    // print(dart['main']);
    // print(dartt['temp']);
    var textHolder = '${weather.toString()}C';
    setState(() {
      c = textHolder;
    });
  }
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    weath();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var c  = weath();
    //print(textHolder);
    //changeText();
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 20),
                child: Text(c),
              ),
            ]))
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Future as return type, as you are returning the value inside async function

```
Future<String> weath() async {
```

Modify the Build method like

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return FutureBuilder(
    future: weath(),
    builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
      return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 20),
          child: Text(snapshot.data.toString()),
        ),
      ])));
    });
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the response but it doesn't work out well

Comment: what you are getting in var textHolder = '${weather.toString()}C'; add print statement & let me know

Comment: I get the correct weather 278.15222222222224C if I print inside the function